# jquery datatables server side filtering causes EF to timeout?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, datatables

I have the following method which filters 2 million records but most of the times if i want to get the last page it causes entity framework to timeout is there any way I could improve the following code so that it can run faster.

```
 public virtual ActionResult GetData(DataTablesParamsModel param)
        {
            try
            {
                int totalRowCount = 0;
                // Generate Data
                var allRecords = _echoMediaRepository.GetMediaList();
                //Apply search criteria to data

                var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<MediaChannelModel>();

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(param.sSearch))
                {
                    var wherePredicate = PredicateBuilder.False<MediaChannelModel>();
                    int i;
                    if (int.TryParse(param.sSearch, out i))
                    {
                        wherePredicate = wherePredicate.Or(m => m.ID == i);
                    }
                    wherePredicate = wherePredicate.Or(m => m.Name.Contains(param.sSearch));

                    predicate = predicate.And(wherePredicate);
                }

                if (param.iMediaGroupID > 0)
                {
                    var wherePredicate = PredicateBuilder.False<MediaChannelModel>();

                    var mediaTypes = new NeptuneRepository<Lookup_MediaTypes>();
                    var mediaGroups = mediaTypes.FindWhere(m => m.MediaGroupID == param.iMediaGroupID)
                    .Select(m => m.Name)
                    .ToArray();

                    wherePredicate = wherePredicate.Or(m => mediaGroups.Contains(m.NeptuneMediaType) || mediaGroups.Contains(m.MediaType));
                    predicate = predicate.And(wherePredicate);
                }

                var filteredRecord = allRecords.Where(predicate);

                var columnCriteria = param.sColumns.Split(',').ToList();
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(columnCriteria[param.iSortCol_0]))
                {
                    filteredRecord = filteredRecord.ApplyOrder(
                        columnCriteria[param.iSortCol_0],
                        param.sSortDir_0 == "asc" ? QuerySortOrder.OrderBy : QuerySortOrder.OrderByDescending);
                }

                totalRowCount = filteredRecord.Count();

                var finalQuery = filteredRecord.Skip(param.iDisplayStart).Take(param.iDisplayLength).ToList();

                // Create response
                return Json(new
                {
                    sEcho = param.sEcho,
                    aaData = finalQuery,
                    iTotalRecords = allRecords.Count(),
                    iTotalDisplayRecords = totalRowCount
                }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Error(ex);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Comment: '_echoMediaRepository.GetMediaList();' does it return IQueryable<T> result?

Comment: yes IQueryable<MediaChannelModel>

Comment: Do you know what query is giving the time out? Probably 'filteredRecord.Skip(param.iDisplayStart).Take(param.iDisplayLength).ToList()'?

Comment: yes that is the one, its the most time consuming query.

Comment: sounds like an sql excecution timeout. The optimisation, if possible (not easy with dynamic query), should be at database side. The hack is to use a greater value for the CommandTimeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code and queries look optimized, so the problem should be the lack of indexes in the database that degrade the performance of your orderby (used by the skip).

Using a test code very similar to yours, I've done some tests in a local test DB with a table with 5 Million rows (with XML Type columns all filled) and, as expected, using queries ordered by indexes was really fast but, by unindexed columns, they could take very, very, long time.

I recommend you to analyse the most common used columns for the dynamic Where and Order functions and do some performance tests by creating the corresponding indexes.